# How to simplify casting of a JToken based on its JTokenType

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there any solution to refactor following switch/case code in a nicer/shorter way ?

- `property.Value` is a `JToken`
- `opportunity` is a CRM Dynamics entity (similar to a Dictionary)

I've tried with following approach without success (it's not acceptable C#)

```
Type target = property.Value.Type.GetType();
opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<target>();
```

---

Here is the code I'm trying to simplify. (`JTokenType.Object` and `JTokenType.Array` are handled in a different way.)

```
                switch (property.Value.Type)
                {
                    case JTokenType.Boolean:
                        opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<bool>();
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Date:
                        opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<DateTime>();
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Integer:
                        opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<int>();
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.String:
                        opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<string>();
                        break;
                    case JTokenType.Guid:
                        opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<Guid>();
                        break;
                }
```

---

I also tried this as suggested by @diiN_:

```
opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<dynamic>();
```

but it throws an InvalidDataContractException:
[image: visual studio exception]

Comment: What about casting it to `dynamic`: `opportunity[property.Key] = property.Value.Value<dynamic>();`?

Comment: unfortunately it's not correctly casting to expected type by CRM Dynamics. updating the question with your suggestion

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this in place of your switch statement:

```
if (property.Value is JValue)
{
    opportunity[property.Key] = ((JValue)property.Value).Value;
}
```

Comment: wonderful solution and sad not finding it. for culture, in my specific example (CRM Dynamics), I had to override the behavior for type Integer because by default json.net cast to Int64 rather Int32 for some specific fields.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps in your situation, but I use a similar piece of code. Maybe give it a try.

```
// prepare return object
returnResult.Value = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// discover data type
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType parseAs = values[prop].Type;

// parse the data and push it as string into the dictionary
if (parseAs == Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.String)
{
    returnResult.Value.Add(prop, (string)values[prop].Value);
}                        
else if (parseAs == Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.Integer)
{
    returnResult.Value.Add(prop, ((Int16)values[prop].Value).ToString());
}
else if (parseAs == Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.Boolean)
{
    returnResult.Value.Add(prop, ((Boolean)values[prop].Value).ToString());
}
else if (parseAs == Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.Array)
{
    // in case of an array, when value is received by the corresponding method
    // the way of deserializing and parsing will be decided then
    returnResult.Value.Add(prop, values[prop].ToString());
}
```